# Does Samsung Galaxy S2 Plus supports Miracast?

Tags: samsung, miracast, samsung-galaxy-s-2-plus

Since Android 4.2 there should be support vor Miracast. Also the Samsung Galaxy S2 Plus has Wifi Direct. But I can't find any option.

Does Samsung Galasy S2 Plus supports Miracast? If yes, where can I find the option in the menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't believe the SGS2 Plus supports Miracast.  [This feature comparison](http://www.phonemore.com/compare/phones/sony-xperia-c-dual-sim-vs-samsung-galaxy-s2-plus-gt-i9105/604012) shows the other phone having it but not the S2.

However, from my understanding, since Wi-Fi Direct is supported it shouldn't be extremely hard for someone to get Miracast working on the device.  [This has been done for the regular SGS2](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s2/help/porting-miracast-to-galaxy-s2-t2464574), though I do not completely understand those posts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does, but probably not on the official ROMs. It is working on CM12 and recent CM11-based ROMs. The broadcom chip inside galaxy s2 plus supports multi-role (but with probably newer drivers), so it even doesn't disconnect from wifi while it is mirroring.